# The action of anti-bumping granules

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, physical-chemistry

[Anti-bumping granules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_chip) are usually small stones. I presume that the principle of these granules ensuring smooth boiling, is that it blocks the upward motion of solution molecules.

Usually the stones have an irregular shape. I am wondering, if the anti-bumping granules are in regular shapes, like a sphere, a cube, will there be some influences to the anti-bumping action of the granules?

Comment: What you call  "Anti-bumping granules" just ave small air pockets, where the water vapor can accumulate and go up. if your water is in a very smooth container, the temperature at the bottom may rise without the vapor escaping,

Comment: Would this question be better suited for [Chemistry.SE]?

Comment: @ Michael Seifert
Actually I'm not quite sure if it should be a physics or chemistry question. But yes, anti-bumping granules are substances used in chemistry

Comment: Cross posted: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/176392/79678.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-bumping stones do not block upward motion of molecules. they are full of tiny fractures and crevices in which air is trapped. That trapped air furnishes nucleation sites for the boiling process to begin the moment the water reaches the boiling point. This prevents the water from becoming *superheated* (a metastable condition) and then spontaneously exploding into vapor all at once (that process is called "bump boiling").